# Spring Cloud Stream Reactive Listener Without Output

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream, project-reactor

I'm using Reactive Spring Cloud Stream and I'm having trouble creating a StreamListener without an Output. The following code works as long as no malformed messages are received. When a malformed message is received, the flux closes.

```
@StreamListener
public void handleMessage(@Input(MessagingConfig.INPUT) Flux<String> payloads) {
    payloads.flatMap(objectToSave -> reactiveMongoTemplate.insert(objectToSave)).subscribe();
}
```

If I understand correctly, it is preferable to let the framework subscribe to the flux instead of subscribing to it manually. This isn't a problem when a listener has an output, because I can simply return the flux like so:

```
@StreamListener
@Output(MessagingConfig.OUTPUT)
public Flux<String> handleMessage(@Input(MessagingConfig.INPUT) Flux<String> payloads) {
    return payloads.flatMap(objectToSave -> reactiveMongoTemplate.insert(objectToSave));
}
```

The framework seems to handle bad messages in a way that doesn't close the flux when it is returned. Is there any way to let the framework handle the flux when the listener doesn't specify an output?

Answer (score 1):

Consider switching to using Spring Cloud Function (SCF) programming model which we have [recently adopted](https://spring.io/blog/2018/10/30/spring-cloud-stream-fishtown-rc1-2-1-0-rc1-release-announcement).
Basically, as long as you have the latest code base (2.1.0.RC4 is the latest and RELEASE is few days away) you're fine. Here is the example of your code using SCF programming model:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class SampleReactiveConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleReactiveConsumer.class, 
                   "--spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=consume");
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Flux<String>> consume(){
        return payloads -> payloads.flatMap(objectToSave -> reactiveMongoTemplate.insert(objectToSave)).subscribe();
    }
}
```

You can also remove reactive module from your classpath as we're also considering deprecating it all together

Comment: What if I want to use my own interface to declare input/output channels instead of using the provided Source/Sink/Processor interfaces? How can I map inputs/outputs in my custom interface to a function? Is there an alternative syntax for "spring.cloud.stream.function.definition" where I can specify a channel?

Comment: At the moment function model only supports standard Source, Processor and Sink and there is a reason for it - primarily to promote microservices style architecture, which is not the same as building general purpose messaging applications with binders. In other words single message listener per microservice, and that is adequately covered by the three interfaces mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid SCF mentioned in Oleg's answer you could try below, hacky approach.

```
const val IN = "input"
const val OUT = "dummy-output"

interface Channels {
    @Input(IN)
    fun input(): MessageChannel

    @Output(OUT)
    fun output(): MessageChannel
}

@EnableBinding(Channels::class)
class MsgList {
    @StreamListener
    @Output(OUT)
    fun receive(@Input(IN) messages: Flux<String>): Flux<Void> {
        return messages
            .doOnNext { if (it == "err") throw IllegalStateException("err") }
            .doOnNext { println(it) }
            .flatMap { Mono.empty<Void>() }
    }
}
```

Output binding will be created but no messages will go through. In case of RabbitMQ that means - dummy exchange will appear, but queue won't get created.

Also errors would be handled as you expected. With above example, you may send 3 messages, "ok", "err", "ok2", and you will see "ok", then exception, then "ok2" on the screen. An "ok2" and any subsequent valid message will be handled properly.

Comment: You're right, this does seem hacky to me. I ended up using the non-reactive StreamListener. It's unfortunate that Spring Could Stream Reactive is being deprecated as many "microservices" don't have one input/output that is assumed with Spring Cloud Function